# Ruby routes and custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, ruby-1.8.7

I'm trying to incorporate Devise and Cancan into a web app. I want users with :role => "admin" to be able to delete users, and Devise's destroy action only allows users to delete themselves, so I've created a custom action for this purpose. (To override the plugin's controller file, I've copied the registrations controller over to app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb.)

Here is my custom action in my registrations_controller.rb:

```
def destroy_user_account
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user])        
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to profiles_path, :flash => { :success => "User deleted!" }
    authorize! :destroy, User, :message => "You don't have authorisation to delete this user."          
end
```

Here is how I'm trying to use it, in a link on the page where you view a user's profile. (I have things set up so that each user has_one profile; profiles are what you see at the front end. A profile is automatically created in the profiles table on user registration.)

```
    <% if can? :update, @profile %>
        | <%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_profile_path(@profile) %>
        | <%= link_to 'Edit Settings', edit_settings_path %>
    <% end %>               
    <% if can? :destroy, @profile.user %>
        | <%= link_to "Delete User", destroy_user_account(@profile.user), 
                        :class => "delete", 
                        :confirm => "Are you sure?",
                        :title => "Delete #{@profile.user.name}"
    %>
    <% end %>
```

My tests are showing 2 failures that I can't resolve:

> 1) ProfilesController GET show when signed in as an admin should
>   have a link to edit the profile
>        Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @profile
>        ActionView::Template::Error:
>          undefined method `destroy_user_account' for #<#<Class:0x105b474a8>:0x1057f32e8>
>        # ./app/views/profiles/show.html.erb:41:in`_app_views_profiles_show_html_erb___917863454_2195331000_0'
>        # ./spec/controllers/profiles_controller_spec.rb:143
>
> 2) ProfilesController GET show when signed in as an admin should
>   have a link to delete the user's account (using the
>   destroy_user_account action in the registrations controller)
>        Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @profile
>        ActionView::Template::Error:
>          undefined method `destroy_user_account' for #<#<Class:0x105b474a8>:0x105806d20>
>        # ./app/views/profiles/show.html.erb:41:in`_app_views_profiles_show_html_erb___917863454_2195331000_0'
>        # ./spec/controllers/profiles_controller_spec.rb:148

Also, when I try it out in my browser, clicking on the "Delete user" link gets me the following error:

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches "/destroy-user-account/2"

Here are the routes that should cover this:

> devise_for :users,  #:path => '', 
>                         :skip => [ :confirmations, :passwords, :registrations ],
>                         :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" } do
>
> ```
> # Routes for ACCOUNT REGISTRATIONS
> get     "join",                           :to => "registrations#new",    :as => :new_user_registration
> post    "join",                           :to => "registrations#create", :as => :user_registration
> get     "settings/account",               :to => "registrations#show",   :as => :settings
> get     "settings/account/edit",          :to => "registrations#edit",   :as => :edit_settings
> put     "settings/account",               :to => "registrations#update", :as => :update_settings
> delete  "close-my-account/:id",           :to => "registrations#destroy", :as => :close_my_account
> delete  "destroy-user-account/:id",      :to => "registrations#destroy_user_account", :as => :destroy_user_account
> ```

Can anyone help with what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the browser it isn't matching the route because you're sending a `GET` request but the route only matches a `DELETE` request. The test fails because the route gives the name `destroy_user_account_path` instead of `destroy_user_account`.

Try:

```
<%= link_to "Delete User", destroy_user_account_path(@profile.user), 
                        :class => "delete", 
                        :confirm => "Are you sure?",
                        :title => "Delete #{@profile.user.name}"
                        :method => :delete
%>
```

Comment: You're of course absolutely right with the destroy_user_account_path thing. Thanks!

Comment: The other, it turns out, was a problem in my action, so all solved. Thanks heaps!!